# Azure Adaljs configuration - what are the "anonymousEndPoints" and "endpoints" properties used for?

Tags: angularjs, azure-active-directory, adal.js

I'm trying to figure out what the "anonymousEndPoints" and "endpoints" property are for. What should the values there be?

There is some vague documentation about it but noting is really clear.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/28/adal-javascript-and-angularjs-deep-dive/):

> Endpoints – this is a very important parameter. ADAL can always tell what token to use when you’re calling your own backend, but without this property it would have no clue on how to handle other API. Endpoints is an array of couples (URL, resourceID). Every time a call to an API is made, ADAL’s interceptor looks up the requested URL in endpoint, then searches the cache for a token with a corresponding resourceID. If it finds it, it uses it; otherwise, it requests a token for that resource, caches it and then uses it. Very handy!